# How do I sort one vector based on values of another in clojure

Tags: sorting, clojure

How do I sort one vector based on the values of another?

Say I have predefined order:

```
(def order ["0M","6M","1Y","2Y","3Y"])
```

I have another vector `["0M","1Y","6M"]` (may or may not contain all elements of vector "order")

Output should be `["0M","6M","1Y"]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(def order ["0M","6M","1Y","2Y","3Y"])

(sort-by #(.indexOf order %) ["0M", "1Y", "6M"]) ; ("0M" "6M" "1Y")
```

Notice that `sort-by` returns a sequence. If you absolutely need a vector result, you can feed the output to `vec`.

Comment: This is a great little solution however it has O(n^2.log n) complexity since each `.indexOf` is O(n). If you have a very large collection, it is better to build a hashmap of objects->index and do `sort-by` using this rather than recalculating `.indexOf` every time.